# reset second initializer of for loop

Tags: java

I've small java code

```
String word = "STUDENT";
    String[] res = new String[20];
    String sub;
    int i, j, k =0;
    int len = word.length();
    for(i = 0;i < len;i++)
    { 
            for(j = 0;j <= len-i;j++,k++)
            {   System.out.println("i :"+i);
                System.out.println("j :"+j);
                sub = word.substring(i, i+j);
                System.out.println("k :"+k);
                 res[k] = sub;
                //for(k = 0;k < res.length;k++)


            }
    }
```

And here is the output

```
i :0
j :0
k :0
i :0
j :1
k :1
i :0
j :2
k :2
i :0
j :3
k :3
i :0
j :4
k :4
i :0
j :5
k :5
i :1
j :0
k :6
i :1
j :1
k :7
i :1
j :2
k :8
i :1
j :3
k :9
i :1
j :4
k :10
i :2
j :0
k :11
i :2
j :1
k :12
i :2
j :2
k :13
i :2
j :3
k :14
i :3
j :0
k :15
i :3
j :1
k :16
i :3
j :2
k :17
i :4
j :0
k :18
i :4
j :1
k :19
```

For just curiosity,  May I know why k is getting incremental every time? Why its not getting reset like j when ever it comes back to the second block ?

Second, How we can reset it like j in block two when it comes from block 1 ?

Comment: Java. Not JavaScript.

Comment: *"May I know why k is getting incremental every time"* - because you explicitly increment it. *"How we can reset it like j"* - `k=0`, like you do with `j`. I don't understand the question here. -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why its not getting reset like j when ever it comes back to the second block ?

because at beginning of`for` you init `j` with zero : `for(j = 0`

> Second, How we can reset it like j in block two when it comes from block 1 ?

you can do like this:

```
for(i = 0;i < len;i++)
{ 
        k=0;
        for(j = 0;j <= len-i;j++,k++)
        {   System.out.println("i :"+i);
            System.out.println("j :"+j);
            sub = word.substring(i, i+j);
            System.out.println("k :"+k);
             res[k] = sub;
            //for(k = 0;k < res.length;k++)


        }
}
```

here we reset `k` value before second for loop start.

Comment: Why not `for(j = 0, k = 0; j <= len-i; j++, k++)`?

Comment: i'm not sure if this work. try it in java. i think it would work too.